# JSF2: Passing a method in an EL expression

Tags: java, jsf-2, el

is it possible to pass a method in an EL expression?

I have one bean and two views. The second view has a button but which method the button triggers should be defined by the first view. So I have to tell the second view the method whe n I link from the first view.

I imagine something like this:

First View:

```html
<h:link outcome="secondView.xhtml" value="Second view with method A">
    <f:param name="methodToCall" value="#{bean.methodA}">
</h:link>
<h:link outcome="secondView.xhtml" value="Second view with method B">
    <f:param name="methodToCall" value="#{bean.methodB}">
</h:link>
```

Second view:

```xml
<h:commandButton action="#{methodToCall}" value="Call the method" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this in JSF. My suggestion would be to have the call from the first view select a delegate in the backing bean which is called when clicking the action from the second view.

Something like this

```
public class Bean {

    public interface Delegate {
        void doSomething();
    }

    public class MethodADelegate implements Delegate {
        public void doSomething() {

        }
    }

    public class MethodBDelegate implements Delegate {
        public void doSomething() {

        }
    }

    private Delegate delegate;

    public String methodA() {
        this.delegate = new MethodADelegate();
        return "view2";
    }

    public String methodB() {
        this.delegate = new MethodBDelegate();
        return "view2";
    }

    public String view2Call() {
        delegate.doSomething();
        return "done";
    }
}

<h:commandLink action="#{bean.methodA}" value="Second view with method A" />
<h:commandLink action="#{bean.methodB}" value="Second view with method B" />

<h:commandButton action="#{bean.view2Call}" value="Call the method" />
```

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible. You can however invoke dynamic bean methods using the brace notation `[]`.

```html
<h:link outcome="secondView.xhtml" value="Second view with method A">
    <f:param name="methodToCall" value="methodA">
</h:link>
<h:link outcome="secondView.xhtml" value="Second view with method B">
    <f:param name="methodToCall" value="methodB">
</h:link>
```

with

```html
<h:commandButton action="#{bean[param.methodToCall]}" value="Call the method" />
```

If the bean needs to be dynamic as well, you'll have to pass the bean name along separately and know its scope.

```html
<h:link outcome="secondView.xhtml" value="Second view with method A">
    <f:param name="beanToCall" value="bean">
    <f:param name="methodToCall" value="methodA">
</h:link>
<h:link outcome="secondView.xhtml" value="Second view with method B">
    <f:param name="beanToCall" value="bean">
    <f:param name="methodToCall" value="methodB">
</h:link>
```

with

```html
<h:commandButton action="#{requestScope[param.beanToCall][param.methodToCall]}" value="Call the method" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Here is the description for `action` attribute:

> MethodExpression representing the application action to invoke when
>   this component is activated by the user. The expression must evaluate
>   to a public method that takes no parameters, and returns an Object
>   (the toString() of which is called to derive the logical outcome)
>   which is passed to the NavigationHandler for this application.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but that's not exactly what Iam looking for. I know, that I can call a method and return a navigation outcome in a action method. What I wanted to know is how I can have a method as a parameter for a new view (or bean).